How to set up custom metrics_path per target?
I have installed node_exporter in several of my servers. I want to add them all together into a main dashboard in Grafana. I grouped up all the targets under the same job_name so I can filter by this in Grafana.
In my prometheus.yml I have configured several targets. All of them are node_exporter/metrics clients:
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: node_exporter
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["nodeexporter.app1.example.com"]
      - targets: ["nodeexporter.app2.example.com"]
      - targets: ["nodeexporter.app3.example.com"]
      - targets: ["nodeexporter.app4.example.com"]
    basic_auth:
      username: 'admin'
      password: 'my_password'

All works good because all these servers share the same default metrics_path and the same basic_auth.
Now I want to add a new target for the job node_exporter. But this one has a different path:
nodeexporter.app5.example.com/extra/metrics

I have tried to add it to the the static_configs but it doesn't work. I have tried:
static_configs:
  [... the other targets]
  - targets: ["nodeexporter.app5.example.com/extra/metrics"]

Also:
static_configs:
  [... the other targets]
  - targets: ["nodeexporter.app5.example.com"]
    __metrics_path__: "/extra/metrics"

Both return a YAML structure error.
How can I configure a custom metrics path for this new app?

I don't remember if override of meta labels supposed to work in the targets list, but even if it is labels must be in labels: block.

Regarding former attempt: path specified there will not work out of the box. You can do that still, just after that you'll need to have a relabel block that will parse target and fill in __address__ and __metrics_path__ appropriately.
